# Query() DynamoDB for each value in array on Lambda NodeJS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have the following code in a NodeJS 12x Lambda function:

```
targetedAliases = ["abc", "efg"]; //Not used yet. But want to replace alias with this array.
alias = "abc" //using this one aka targetedAliases[0].

const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    apiVersion: "2012-10-08"
});
var aliasScores;


const params = {
    TableName: 'a-table',
    FilterExpression: '#alias = :alias',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#alias': 'alias',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':alias': {
            S: alias
        },
    }
};

aliasScores = await dynamoDB.scan(params).promise();

console.log("====> ", aliasScores);
```

The function as is prints the content of `aliasScores` as expected but I need to execute this `n` times for each item on the `targetedAliases` array.

Is there a way I can use a `Array.forEach` or something similar to execute a query/scan iteratively for each item in an array? Alternatively, can I use an array on the `FilterExpression` to execute the query/scan just once?

I want store each query/scan result in the `aliasScores` variable as a concatenation of all returned objects to use it further below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all` with `.map` to execute these in parallel and get the results in array. Something like this

```
const targetedAliases = ["abc", "efg"]; //Not used yet. But want to replace alias with this array.
alias = "abc" //using this one aka targetedAliases[0].

const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB({
    apiVersion: "2012-10-08"
});
var aliasScores;

const result = await Promise.all(targetedAliases.map(alias => {
  const params = {
    TableName: 'a-table',
    FilterExpression: '#alias = :alias',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
        '#alias': 'alias',
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':alias': {
            S: alias
        },
    }
};

return dynamoDB.scan(params).promise();
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: changing alias to array will result in this error as it expects it to be string. You need to iterate through array and for each item send the query. The way I have done

Comment: Yes sorry I noticed that... I do get an error on `const aliasScores = await dynamoDB.Scan(params).promise();` ... It says "unexpected  token dynamoDB", if I remove `await` error goes away. Are we missing an `async`?

Comment: Why `await dynamoDB.scan()` within the map when all of the promises are later awaited via Promise.all? Presumably you should just `return dynamoDB.scan(params).promise()`.

Comment: The scan runs successfully but seems like aliasScores is being overwritten instead of getting items appended to it.  `targetedAliases[0]` returns 57 items and `targetedAliases[1]` returns 20 items for a total of 77. But I get just 20.  If I leave just `targetedAliases[0]` I get 57.

Comment: Just use the result variable which will have results from both calls. see my updated answer.

Comment: Ok that helped! But output seems weird please see [Output](https://0bin.net/paste/ecs5Is0YoHBBvX2S#RrehgirHvPgaRpCX2aix6uaGFG7KmZMEnuSfBh-TPZM). It's printing it twice. I changed you last line to `console.log("====>", result)` to see it better. If you check the output on the link above, it seems like it's duplicating the data?

Comment: Huh, I commented out the `console.log("====>", result)` line and I'm now getting just one dump of data. I think your answer is correct, Ashish! I'm new to AWS stuff sorry for the silly mistakes. I appreciate your help sir!

Answer (score 1):

Your options kinda depend on whether the attribute alias is a primary key or not.  Just knowing this difference will help a lot.

Promise.all() executes one operation for each alias. Consider the batch approach. A single batch for executes in one API invocation which will reduce the number of operations and reduce your DynamoDB API calls. Batching is fun.

When the attribute key 'alias' is the primary key, BatchGetItem a is very efficient operation for up to a dozen or so operations where each operation is a query for one alias.  Just create a single BatchGetItem with one operation for each entry in the array.  The response is a single json dictionary.

When the attribute key 'alias' is not the primary key then it's different because the table must be scanned. A DynamoDB [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html)() is different than a DynamoDB [query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)(). scan can find items by any attribute and can filter by the value of 'alias.'  The FilterExpression supports OR and it is possible to filter the scan. The scan will check every item and the filter just reduces the returned result set.  The response is a single json dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I ended up changing it to a query but i will definitely look into batch operations!

Comment: Sounds good.  query() is goodness. The forEach approach certainly keeps the query() responses in order so that you can create a concatenated result array aliasScore.  BatchGetItem will order results too however a single scan operation with a FilterExpression will not.